# changing bgcolor when boolean changes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Novice programmer here.

I am trying to change the background color going forward when a boolean changes (either highBroken or lowBroken) and have it persist until the other boolean changes to true then have the color switch again and persist.

bgcolor(highBroken?color.green : na, editable = true, transp=80)
bgcolor(lowBroken?color.red : na, editable = true, transp=80)

Currently its only changing for the bar that its triggered on. If I turn off the na, it fills both colors all the time.

[image]

I tried the above code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a boolean that switches from false to true when the condition is met and vice versa. You also want to use var so it is not reset on every bar.

In this example I have a boolean set to false, when the 8ema crosses above the 21 ema it switches to true and then changes the background color until the condition is no longer true.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
ema8 = ta.ema(close, 8)
ema21 = ta.ema(close, 21)
var myBool = false
myBool := ema8 > ema21 ? true : false
bgcolor(myBool ? color.new(color.blue, 80) : na)
```

You could also write it with if statements like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
ema8 = ta.ema(close, 8)
ema21 = ta.ema(close, 21)
var myBool = false
if ema8 > ema21
    myBool := true
else
    myBool := false
bgcolor(myBool ? color.new(color.blue, 80) : na)
```